# angular 2 *ngFor and Observables Object, no data displayed

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular2-observables

I've checked a certain questions already, but still didn't manage to solve my issue. I'm using a service in my app which returns observables, everything is fine on this stage, but when I want to display the data, nothing happens:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    private APIURL = 'http://api.dev/'; 

    constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

    _API_getEvents:string = this.APIURL + "getEvents";
    getEvents() : Observable<IEvent[]> {
        return this.http.get(this._API_getEvents)
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
          const body = error.json() || '';
          const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
          errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
          errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }


}
```

Event Interface:

```
export interface IEvent {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    created_at:Date;
    update_at:Date;
}
```

And component:

```
events:IEvent[];
//events:any[];

  constructor(private _http:Http, private _dataService: DataService)
  {
    this._dataService.getEvents()
    .subscribe(

      function(response) { console.log("Success Response" + response); 

        this.events = response;
        console.log('EVENTS: ');
        console.log(this.events);
      },
      function(error) { console.log("Error happened" + error)},
      function() { console.log("the subscription is completed")}
    );
  }
```

When I'm trying to display, its empty:

```
 <ul *ngIf="events">
                    <li *ngFor="let event of events">
                        <a [routerLink]="['/gallery/', 'event1']">
                            {{event.name}}
                        </a>
                    </li>
...
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Can you put ur code in plunkr? I can hardly find anything that is not working. Assuming that data is being consoled on the componenet level.

Comment: So far console.log shows that data was obtained successfully but I got a feeling that view rendered before that. But when I search on similar topics , people usually add *ngIf directive and it solves the issue, but in my case it's not. I'll try to create plunkr

Comment: I'd also recommend moving your code in your constructor to ngOnInit. If you eventually start using Input bindings on your component, it won't work the way you might expect, because when the constructor is called, Angular hasn't yet initalised any bindings. It's just good practice do minimize the work you do in your component's constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow functions. Without them, `this` is not bound to the component instance in your calback functions:

```
.subscribe(response => { 
    console.log("Success Response" + response); 
    this.events = response;
}, 
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! SOLVED :)